# Обработка Telegram ответа на нажатие по кнопке

Tags: php, button, telegram

Пишу на php, использую для написания кода библиотеку https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core

Код выглядит так

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\InlineKeyboard;

$telegram = new Telegram(ТОКЕН);

$keyboard = InlineKeyboard::forceReply([['callback_data' => 'data_test', 'text' => '1'],
                ['callback_data' => 'data_test2', 'text' => '2']]);

$result = Request::sendPhoto(['chat_id' => '-1001385232215', 'photo' => Request::encodeFile('22-03-2018_00-03-47.jpeg'), 'caption' => "Описание.", 'reply_markup' => $keyboard]);
```

Боту приходит сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму, как сделать обработку для кнопок. Не могу найти даже примера кода.

Comment: решистрируете для бота callback (т.е. ссылку на вашем сервере, которую он будет дергать при нажатии) и он будет посылать на нее запрос. А вообще доку на телеграмму почитайте, там все понятно расписано

Comment: @rjhdby а можно пример, где используется это все?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core

Попробуй использовать вот эту библиотеку, там есть функция для вызова Callback по этим кнопочкам